# Форма ajax неверно работает

Tags: ajax

есть обработчик формы ajax

```
  $("form#dataler").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData(this);

    $.ajax({
      url: 'sendler.php',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'html',
      data: formData,
      success: function success(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('.header__call-form').hide();
        $('.header__call-form--success').show();
        $('.header__call-form--success > .name').text(formData.get('name'));
      },
      error: function error(data) {
        console.log('error');
        // после отправки формы в консоле выводится массив с получеными данными
      },
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false
    });
  });
```

и валидация формы:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dataler').each(function() {
        $(this).validate({
            // правила для полей с именем и паролем
            rules:{

                name:{
                    required: true, // поле для имени обязательное для заполнения
                    minlength: 1, // в поле для имени должно быть не меньше 4 символов
                },

                phone:{
                    required: true, // поле для пароля обязательное для заполнения
                    minlength: 6, // в поле для пароля должно быть не меньше 6 символов
                    maxlength: 16, // в поле для пароля должно быть не больше 16 символов
                },
            },
            // сообщение для поля с именем и пароля, если что-то было не по правилам
            messages:{

                name:{
                    required: "", // сообщение для имени, если поле не заполнено
                    minlength: "", // сообщение для имени, если в поле меньше 4 символов
                    maxlength: " Максимальное число символов для имени - 16", // сообщение для имени, если в поле больше 16 символов
                },

                phone:{
                    required: "", // сообщение для пароля, если поле не заполнено
                    minlength: "", // сообщение для пароля, если в поле меньше 6 символов
                    maxlength: "", // сообщение для пароля, если в поле больше 16 символов
                },

            }

        });
    });

});
```

Но у меня всё равно форма проходит далее через функцию success, выдавая сообщение что заявка отправлена, не понимаю что сделал не так

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по строке

```
$('#dataler').each(function() {
```

в Вашей странице несколько форм с `id="dataler"`, и Вы ожидаете, что выборка `$('#dataler')` будет содержать их все. Однако, выбор элементов по `id` исходит из того, что значения атрибута `id` на странице уникальны и не повторяются. Так что выборка `$('#dataler')` будет содержать максимум один элемент.

https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#dataler').validate({
    rules:{
      // ...
    },
    messages:{
      // ...
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      var formData = new FormData(form);
      $.ajax({
        // ...
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: нет, форма одна

Comment: попробовал без each, тот же результат

Comment: @StepanIvanov Попробуйте переставить эти куски кода местами.

Comment: делал, не помогло